# const {function Name} = function code... What is this syntax called?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I am currently looking over some code and the developer wrote the following function:

```
const {functionName} = ...some code...
```

I haven't seen this type of syntax before. What is this type of function syntax called and what is it used for?

Comment: In case of variables it's called [Object destructuring](http://n-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). That would be something like:
`const { name, age } = person`. But I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: What @fravolt said is right but if you can share the code we can give a better and detailed answer.

Comment: Yes @fravolt, this is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks!
Edit: The Hyperlink doesn't work for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Destructuring assignment.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment for details.